# baked seitan left out

Tags: vegan, vegetarian

So I left  my baked seitan out for 3 to 4 hours today. I was going to toss it but then I was like wait.. it's a dry product much like bread.. is my thinking ok and it's fine still?  I bake it in a non stick pan with aluminum foil over the top to keep the steam in. it's at 350 for about 35 minutes.   I use water, wheat gluten, about 30 grams of yeast flakes, 50 grams of almond flour and graham flour each and some spices. it's basically like bread right? should be fine since it's dry not wet?

this is not covered or related to the thing that I got flagged for. that does not answer this question

Comment: If your seitan is supposed to be refrigerated after making it, then the linked duplicate applies. Even if it's not (e.g. it's considered a "bread" like product for food safety purposes, that's still discussed in the canonical question :)

Comment: is it though? it's a home made recipe. I do refrigerate it but does it need to be? I don't know.  most seitan is made via boiling not baking. IS it like a bread? does hte high protein content change things? it's a valid question that is not covered in the other thread.  they're different products. wow this community is rude.

Comment: @user73568 fair questions, but accusations of rudeness?  I don't see it.  We post comments and answers, the community votes.  The best responses rise to the surface.  It's all in the spirit of documenting the knowledge.  I won't say I've never seen rudeness here, but there is nothing in this back and forth that even comes close.  Give it some time.  I am sure you question will be answered.

Comment: You might want to rephrase what you've asked so it's more clear. Specifics about whether the protein content changes shelf life, for example, aren't covered in the other question. We cannot say one way or another "this batch of seitan is safe" any more definitively than the two hour limit in the linked question, but if you refocus maybe it will stay open. (I also suggest the [tour] to get a better idea of how StackExchange is different from a typical forum community.)

Comment: @user73568 the default assumption for a cooked food is that it has to be refrigerated. Unless the person who created the recipe can prove that it is safe at room temperature, then it counts in the "needs refrigeration" category, and we cannot tell you anything different from looking at the recipe itself.